# Nested inline element 'vertical-align' behaves different on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, frontend, inline, vertical-alignment

I put a span element inside a span, and set `vertical-align: 20px` for the outer span and `vertical-align: top` for the inner span. HTML and CSS code is here.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/zeigo/pen/BaQazgq)

```css
.mid {
  vertical-align: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.right {
  vertical-align: top;
    outline: 1px solid;
}

.se {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p class="out">A<span class="mid">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

On Chrome, it shows

[image]

On Firefox, it shows

[image]

Which is the standard behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

If we follow [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height) describing line boxes we can read:

> As described in the section on inline formatting contexts, user agents flow inline-level boxes into a vertical stack of line boxes. The height of a line box is determined as follows:
>
> 1. The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements, this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is their 'line-height'.
> 2. The inline-level boxes are aligned vertically according to their 'vertical-align' property. In case they are aligned 'top' or 'bottom', they must be aligned so as to minimize the line box height.
> 3. The line box height is the distance between **the uppermost box top and the lowermost box bottom.** (This includes the strut, as explained under 'line-height' below.)

In Chrome the element is clearly outside its line box so it sounds like a bug for me. If we add border we can clearly see the overflow:

```css
.mid {
  vertical-align: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.right {
  vertical-align: top;
    outline: 1px solid;
}

.se {
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p class="out">A<span class="mid">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Another intresting result if you set `vertical-align:-20px`

```css
.mid {
  vertical-align: -20px;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.right {
  vertical-align: top;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.se {
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p class="out">A<span class="mid">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Firefox will make the C element to stick to the top of the `p` which is the logical result. Chrome will *again* do things differently and I think it's also a bug.

---

Worth to note that if you make the `mid` element inline-block you will have a consistant behavior since the alignment is easier and both browsers and C will now consider the line box inside `mid` and will always stick to its top

```css
.mid {
  vertical-align: -20px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
}

.right {
  vertical-align: top;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.se {
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p class="out">A<span class="mid">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>

<p class="out">A<span class="mid" style="vertical-align: 20px">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>
```

---

Well, it seems that there is a logical explanation to what chrome is doing if we follow the exmaple below

```css
.mid {
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.right {
  vertical-align: top;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.se {
  vertical-align: 40px;
}

p {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class="out">A<span class="mid" style="vertical-align:baseline">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>

<p class="out">A<span class="mid" style="vertical-align: 20px;">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>

<p class="out">A<span class="mid" style="vertical-align: 40px">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>

<p class="out">A<span class="mid" style="vertical-align:-20px">B<span class="right">C</span>D</span><span class="se">E</span></p>
```

It seems that chrome is first placing the C element at the top (considering a default baseline alignment to `mid`) then aligning the mid element which create the strange result. The C is shifted by the pixel value set to `vertical-align` of `.mid` element from the top.